# aborting after fassert() failure On Mac

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am creating an express app with Nodejs & MongoDB, this is my first time.

When I run this command,

```
   mongod --dbpath SM:NodeTestApp101\data
```

I am getting this error

```
015-11-08T08:24:01.771-0700 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to 
unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:13 Permission denied
2015-11-08T08:24:01.771-0700 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal 
Assertion 28578
2015-11-08T08:24:01.771-0700 I -        [initandlisten] 
***aborting after fassert() failure
```

I am new with MongoDB and have no idea what it means, I have google it and have had no luck solving this issue.

Is there anyone that can help me with it? I can provide more information if needed, Please just let me know.